# (sml/nj) Correct type?

Tags: types, functional-programming, sml

For my assignment I have to do two functions with the type:

```
 wt: trie -> (char list list -> ’a)-> ’a
 aw: trie list -> (char list list -> ’a)-> ’a
```

but what I have is this and was wondering if it was the same thing:

```
 wt: 'a trie -> ('a list list -> ’a list list)-> ’a list list 
 aw: 'a trie list -> ('a list list -> ’a list list)-> ’a list list
```

This is my function:

```
datatype ’a trie = Node of ’a * (’a trie) list | Empty

fun words_in_trie Empty cont = cont [[]]
    | words_in_trie (Node (c, lis)) cont = all_words lis (fn j => map (fn y => [c]@y) j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are not the same. For each of them, look at the second parameter, the function. Your assignment says:

```
char list list -> 'a
```

Your version says:

```
'a list list -> ’a list list
```

Okay, so let's assume that in your function, `'a` is `char`. That means that we can rewrite it to

```
char list list -> char list list
```

Which is different from what the assignment says. Of course, the `'a` in the assignment *could* in theory be a `char list list`, but when it's specified as `'a`, that probably means that your teachers want it to be generic.